# Repeating images in a ffmpeg -i %04d.png pattern

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm making a video of 20 seconds at FPS=25,  with 500 frames which are `0000.png`, `0001.png`, ..., `0499.png`. This works:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i images/%04d.png out.mp4
```

but in fact there are *only a few changes* in the video, in my case at frames 0000, 0122, 0288, 0312, 0450. In the meantime the PNG **are identical**.

Problem: it's always slow to generate 500 PNG files when only 5 different files would be enough! I would like to generate only those 5 PNG files, and generate the video from them.

When I try the command above with `images/` containing **only** `0000.png`, `0122.png`, `0288.png`, `0312.png`, `0450.png` **and not the 495 others**, obviously it fails with:

> [image2 @ 00000000006d4040] Could not open file : images/0001.png

**Question: is there a way to tell `ffmpeg` to ignore missing frames and use the latest available frame instead of failing, when using `-i images/%04d.png`?**

If not, what alternative is there to generate the video with only these 5 PNG that should arrive at a precise timeframe?

Comment: Should all images display for the same duration (such as 1 second each), or will they be arbitrary? For example, 0000 for 5 seconds, 0122 or 2 seconds, etc.

Comment: @llogan not the same duration. 0000 should stay during 122 frames, then 0122.png should stay until frame #288, so it should stay 288-122=166 frames, etc.

Comment: Will you know which frames are unique and how long each should display for? Or is it a requirement that it is all automated?

Comment: Yes I know in advance which frames are unique @llogan, so I only need to display 0000.png during 122 frames, 0122.png during frames 122 to 287, 0288.png during the next frames etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Method 1: concat filter

Declare duration with `-t` input options and then concatenate with the [concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat).

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 25 -t 4.88 -i 0000.png -loop 1 -framerate 25 -t 6.64 -i 0122.png -loop 1 -framerate 25 -t 0.96 -i 0288.png -loop 1 -framerate 25 -t 00:00:05.52 -i 0312.png -filter_complex "[0][1][2][3]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p" output.mp4
```

## Method 2: concat demuxer

Declare duration with `duration` directive in the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) input file list, and then concatenate with the concat demuxer.

This may be the fastest method.

1. Make `input.txt` containing the following:

   ```
   file 0000.png
   duration 4.88
   file 0122.png
   duration 6.64
   file 0288.png
   duration 0.96
   file 0312.png
   duration 5.52
   ```
2. Concatenate:

   ```
   ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -vf format=yuv420p output.mp4
   ```

## Method 3: trim filter

This method lets you declare the duration either in frames (and/or by using a time value if you prefer).

Example using frames for duration with the [trim filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#trim) and concatenate with the [concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat):

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 25 -i 0000.png -loop 1 -framerate 25 -i 0122.png -loop 1 -framerate 25 -i 0288.png -loop 1 -framerate 25 -i 0312.png -filter_complex "[0]trim=start_frame=0:end_frame=121,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];[1]trim=start_frame=122:end_frame=287,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];[2]trim=start_frame=288:end_frame=311,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2];[3]trim=start_frame=312:end_frame=449,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v3];[v0][v1][v2][v3]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p" output.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @llogan, I'll try all of them! PS: ultimately, I'll mix/overlay these 500 frames (coming from these PNG files) with other videos (using `overlay` `filter_complex`) like `test.mp4` which begins at frame 250 until frame 600. Are all these 3 methods compatible with this `overlay`?

Comment: @Basj They are all compatible with overlay.

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity, why do you use `format=yuv420p` specifically? Is it important to specify the YUV color space? If we don't mention it and keep the default value, will it be not as good as with yuv420p?

Comment: PS @llogan: just in case you have an idea (and time to look at it ;)), I have a tricky issue with setting overlay orders:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66459251/overlay-of-multiple-sources-with-layer-order-like-css-z-index

Comment: @Basj ffmpeg tries to preserve chroma integrity, but not all players can handle the results, so when going from images to MP4 using `format=yuv420p` ensures compatible chroma subsampling.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I tried the loops method yesterday and I found that it may takes even longer time for encoding the video then the image sequence if you have a dated cpu. (also I broke my laptop for good).
I think it's because even with 5 images ffmpeg has always to read 500 frames to encode the video.
Since the concern is the encoding efficency, read this encoding guide
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264
and get back to your code. The -framerate is 25 by default and you don't need to declare it

`ffmpeg -y -f image2 -pattern_type sequence -i images/%04d.png -c:v h264 -crf 51 -preset 'ultrafast' out.mp4`

the declaring of " -f image2 -pattern_type sequence" theoretically should spare the time of probing the file.

-crf and presets are the encoding bread and butter and that code should give you the fastest encoding times at the cost of low quality, try that and gradually decrease values untill you reach an acceptable quality.

Last but not least the thing that is slowing down the encoding is the format you are using: the PNG use a huge colorspace of 256x256x256 colors, they can be uncompressed (1file=30mb).
if you don't need the alpha channel, try with jpegs and things will go much faster.